# How to use UNIX Timestamp value for today's date in PHP/MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, unix-timestamp

I want to fetch all the records whose transaction_date falls today e.g. (12th February 2014). So to achieve this I tried following SQL query:

```
SELECT transaction_status, count( * ) AS StatusCount
FROM OCN.user_transaction
WHERE transaction_date = date('Ymd')
GROUP BY transaction_status
```

But it's not working for me. Can anyone help me in this regard please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the column type of `transaction_date` ?

Comment: how is transaction date saved in db? date or datetime or timestamp?

Comment: @Rikesh:The data type is bigint(12)

Comment: Presuming UNIX timestamp, presuming MySQL; `select ... where date(now()) = date(from_unixtime(transaction_date)) ...;`.

Answer (score 3):

If data type is BigInt(12) then this should work for you:

```
SELECT
    transaction_status, 
    count( * ) AS StatusCount 
FROM 
    OCN.user_transaction 
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date), "%Y-%m-%d") = DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY 
    transaction_status
```

But using BigInt to store timestamps is not the best way to store date in MySQL. You can use DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You would do worse than to use the [CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
  transaction_status,
  COUNT(*) AS StatusCount 
FROM
  OCN.user_transaction 
WHERE transaction_date = CURDATE()
GROUP BY transaction_status
```

If you've further questions, do leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing 2 different date-time formats, so parse the 'transaction_date' to the same date-time format as the input date. Use DATE_FORMAT(date,format) for this problem.

example implementation:

```
    SELECT transaction_status, 
         count( * ) AS StatusCount 
    FROM OCN.user_transaction 
   WHERE DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date, "Ymd") = date('Ymd') 
GROUP BY transaction_status
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
transaction_status,
COUNT(*) AS StatusCount 
FROM
OCN.user_transaction 
WHERE transaction_date =date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "%d-%m-%y")
GROUP BY transaction_status ;
```

You can modify the format as you want.

Answer (score 1):

The current date method returns today's date...So i believe the post that was submitted by hd1 should work.

SELECT 
  transaction_status,
  COUNT(*) AS StatusCount 
FROM
  OCN.user_transaction 
WHERE transaction_date = CURDATE()
GROUP BY transaction_status

Answer (score -2):

if `transaction_date` is timestamp type, and query create by php, try this:

```
SELECT 
  transaction_status,
  COUNT(*) AS StatusCount 
FROM
  OCN.user_transaction 
WHERE transaction_date = <?php time() ?>
GROUP BY transaction_status
```

else try mysql now() function

```
SELECT 
  transaction_status,
  COUNT(*) AS StatusCount 
FROM
  OCN.user_transaction 
WHERE transaction_date = now()
GROUP BY transaction_status
```